# Increasing iframe height

Tags: jquery, iframe, load

I am loading a "html" page in to a div( ex: #targets) using jquery load().The the div comes under the iframe. After loading the html file, the div height and iframe height not getting increased based on the html file content height.

How to change the iframe and div height based on the htm contents in the div.

Comment: Any feedback to the answers given? Do none work out for you???

Answer (score 0):

try this css code:

```
div, iframe
{
  overflow:auto;
  height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading this blog post

[jQuery iFrame Sizing](http://sonspring.com/journal/jquery-iframe-sizing)

```
// For some browsers (for opera, safari check blog post, chrome?)
$('iframe').load(function() {
    this.style.height =
    this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
});
```